# How to distribute a windows phone 7 application from within an intranet

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a windows phone 7 application which I need to distribute to elements of my company. How can I achieve this? I do not want the application to be on the marketplace because it is a corporate application which should only be visible and used by elements of the organization.

Is this possible?

Best regards,
Bruno

Comment: I guess this feature will be available on Mango according to this article:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-readies-private-marketplace-feature-for-windows-phones/9198

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 options currently open to you:

- You could use Beta distribution as Tom says, but that's limited to 90 days and no updates.
- You could also publish the application on Marketplace, but make it hidden so that other users cannot search for it. You would need to send your users a link so that they could install the app. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334584%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

However for the 2nd option you should beware that anyone would be able to install the application if they know the link for it. So if you need it to be secure you need to provide some other mechanism to lock it down.

Comment: If the hidden-yet-in-the-Marketplace option is not secure enough, another consideration could be putting a soft lock on the app. Make the app ask the user for a Passcode to activate. This way, even if someone downloads the app from a leaked deep-link, they cannot do anything with it. Passcodes can be generated internally using various combinations of AD, Device ID etc. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There has been news about a private distribution model for corporate applications, but this is not available yet. For now you can use the private beta distribution for this purpose, all you need is a list of the Live IDs used by the people within your company. 
I wrote a blog explaining private beta functionality, you can find it [here](http://blog.tomverhoeff.nl/2011/08/13/using-private-beta-distribution-for-testing-your-wp7-app/)